# How To Find Individual Record Based On Properties Other Than ID In Ember View

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to find an individual record based on its property in the views in Ember 1.0.0-rc.5? I've been searching around for days, but I still can't find anything that works.

For example, I would like to be able to do this:

`App.Tag.find({name: 'some tag'})` which is supposed to return one record, but instead returns an array.

The name field is unique for all tags, so it should return only one object.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved! For people who might encounter the same problem, I will answer my question here. I ended up using the filter method to select one object. Details here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filter

Code:

```
...
tagList = App.Tag.find().filter (item, index, enumerable) ->
    return item.get('slug') is "slug title"

tag = tagList.get('firstObject')
...
```

Comment: the link to the docs now say to use `.find` or `.findBy` on an enumerable to return a single object. (Note: this is different from using `.find` on `store`, which fires a query, and returns an array. The difference is the object you're calling it on, the message receiver)

Answer (score 1):

When passing a query to a model's find method, you're invoking the findQuery method, which is designed to populate an array.

This is findQuery's definition:

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query, recordArray) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type),
    adapter = this;

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "GET", {
      data: query
    }).then(function(json){
      adapter.didFindQuery(store, type, json, recordArray);
    }).then(null, rejectionHandler);
  },
```

Which then calls didFindQuery upon success, to populate the array which is returned:

```
didFindQuery: function(store, type, payload, recordArray) {
    var loader = DS.loaderFor(store);

    loader.populateArray = function(data) {
      recordArray.load(data);
    };

    get(this, 'serializer').extractMany(loader, payload, type);
  },
```

So, assuming my understanding is correct, given that each 'name' in your case is unique, just get the first key of your array:

```
var tags = App.Tag.find({name: 'some tag'});
var tag = tags[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. However, you simply cannot get an object in an array in Ember - it will just return undefined. I actually ended up using the filter method. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @user14412 - Ah right, glad you found a solution. Looks like we both learned something. :)

Comment: I know this is old but I wanted to add for anyone coming across this to do [0] you can do tags.get("firstObject") http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/#toc_first-and-last-objects

Comment: I've actually found that you have to do `.findBy('yourType', 'yourValue')` on a returned array, or `.find(item, index, controller) -> item.property == 'stringValue'`